# Bluetooth headset can no longer be connected

Tags: bluetooth

since today my Marshall Major 3 can't be connected to my laptop. I never had any issued until today, but now i only can appair to it, and when i try to connect to my hedset i have the error:

> impossible connection

My headset works fine with my phone, so i really think the problem comes from Elementary...

ps: I have an Huawei matebook D if that can help

edit:
journalctl returns the following response each time I try to connect to my headset:

> bluetoothd[10401]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for 2C:4D:79:C1:3E:11: Protocol not available

Also, i can't remember which command I've typed for that, but I saw some segfault reffereing to the bluetooth. I know it's not very useful.

I searched some fixes for the "Protocol not available" issue, and a possible fix would be to install "pulseaudio-module-bluetooth", but when I try to install it, i get the following error:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    pulseaudio-module-bluetooth :
>   Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.4) but 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.5 is to be installed
>   Depends: pulseaudio (= 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.4)
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Are you able to provide some related logs from syslog or journalctl?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've edited my original post with these informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This fix is surely dirty, but it worked for me**

I managed to resolve my problem;
The problem was libpulse0 which has been upgraded to the version 7.5 while the required version was the 7.4.

I've reinstalled the 7.4 version:

> sudo apt install libpulse0=1:11.1-1ubuntu7.4
>   sudo apt-mark hold libpulse0

(apt-mark hold is used to prevent the upgrade of libpulse0 in the future)

After that, when I restarted my laptop i could no longer login (session returned 1), so I installed "pantheon-xsession-settings" (press ctrl+alt+f1 to enter in the terminal mode), rebooted and everything worked fine. (and so the bluetooth)

I think the installation of libpulse0 v7.4 removed some important packages, that's why I had to install "pantheon-xsession-settings"

Comment: I run `apt install --dry-run libpulse0=1:11.1-1ubuntu7.4` and indeed it seems to remove stuff like `elementary-desktop`, `gala` etc. I also noticed that `io.elementary.cerbere` is listed as no longer needed, which is odd. I think I will file a bug report.

Comment: So I've found a bug that might be related, I added some info there: https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-bluetooth/issues/103#issuecomment-589599047

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type

```
sudo apt install blueman

sudo apt install nano

sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

Change `#AutoEnable=false` to `AutoEnable=true` (at the bottom of the file, by default)

Save using ctrl+x
Exit

```
sudo service /etc/init.d/bluetooth
```

or

```
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth

sudo systemctl start bluetooth
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but AutoEnable was already set to true

Comment: Did you do all steps I mentioned or only you switched AutoEnable to true?

Comment: AutoEnable was already to True so I didn't switched it, but I still executed the commands you gave